# Gradle Error while instrumenting class

Tags: testing, gradle, task, instrumentation, jacoco

I’m working on a POC with Jacoco and gradle for GigaProject and am getting this error when it gets to jacoco during "test" task aka instrumenting test source code. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException: Error while instrumenting class org/gradle/internal/service/UnknownServiceException.
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_5d10cad.CoverageTransformer.transform(CoverageTransformer.java:91)
        at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:169)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:365)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.child.ImplementationClassLoaderWorker.createLoggingManager(ImplementationClassLoaderWorker.java:85)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.child.ImplementationClassLoaderWorker.execute(ImplementationClassLoaderWorker.java:53)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.child.ImplementationClassLoaderWorker.execute(ImplementationClassLoaderWorker.java:37)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:43)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:32)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.launcher.BootstrapClassLoaderWorker.call(BootstrapClassLoaderWorker.java:46)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.launcher.BootstrapClassLoaderWorker.call(BootstrapClassLoaderWorker.java:32)
        at jarjar.org.gradle.process.internal.launcher.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:32)
        at jarjar.org.gradle.process.internal.launcher.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:37)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: build\jacoco\UT\classpathdumps\org\gradle\internal\service\UnknownServiceException.class (The requested oper
ation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:194)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:145)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_5d10cad.ClassFileDumper.dump(ClassFileDumper.java:66)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_5d10cad.CoverageTransformer.transform(CoverageTransformer.java:83)
        ... 22 more
java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException: Error while instrumenting class org/gradle/logging/internal/DefaultStandardOutputRedirector$WriteAct
ion.
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_5d10cad.CoverageTransformer.transform(CoverageTransformer.java:91)
        at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:169)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:365)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:295)
        at org.gradle.util.FilteringClassLoader.loadClass(FilteringClassLoader.java:60)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at org.gradle.util.MultiParentClassLoader.loadClass(MultiParentClassLoader.java:52)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:295)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at org.gradle.logging.internal.DefaultStandardOutputRedirector.<init>(DefaultStandardOutputRedirector.java:30)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JULRedirector.<init>(JULRedirector.java:29)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestFramework$TestClassProcessorFactoryImpl.create(JUnitTestFramework.java:96)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.startReceivingTests(TestWorker.java:81)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:44)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:78)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:35)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.child.ImplementationClassLoaderWorker.execute(ImplementationClassLoaderWorker.java:81)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.child.ImplementationClassLoaderWorker.execute(ImplementationClassLoaderWorker.java:37)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:43)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:32)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.launcher.BootstrapClassLoaderWorker.call(BootstrapClassLoaderWorker.java:46)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.launcher.BootstrapClassLoaderWorker.call(BootstrapClassLoaderWorker.java:32)
        at jarjar.org.gradle.process.internal.launcher.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:32)
        at jarjar.org.gradle.process.internal.launcher.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:37)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: build\jacoco\UT\classpathdumps\org\gradle\logging\internal\DefaultStandardOutputRedirector$WriteAction.class
(The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:194)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:145)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_5d10cad.ClassFileDumper.dump(ClassFileDumper.java:66)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_5d10cad.CoverageTransformer.transform(CoverageTransformer.java:83)
        ... 34 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, that was quick. I had the following test {... } section in Gradle build.gradle file and it was using classDumpPath setting (custom folder set at my end).

```
   test {
     maxParallelForks = 5
     forkEvery = 50
     ignoreFailures = true

     testReportDir = file("$buildDir/reports/tests/UT")
     testResultsDir = file("$buildDir/test-results/UT")


     //Following Jacoco test section is required only in Jenkins instance extra common file
     jacoco {
        //The following vars works ONLY with 1.6 of Gradle
        destPath = file("$buildDir/jacoco/UT/jacocoUT.exec")
        classDumpPath = file("$buildDir/jacoco/UT/classpathdumps")

        //Following vars works only with versions >= 1.7 version of Gradle
        //destinationFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/UT/jacocoUT.exec")
        //  classDumpFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/UT/classpathdumps")
     }
   }
```

Commenting the following line, did the trick. I'll look into it later, why it solved the issue.

```
//--- classDumpPath = file("$buildDir/jacoco/UT/classpathdumps")
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem. what helped me was to change the JRE version.
changed it from 15 to 14.